# Update value inside mongodb array object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update a value inside my array of objects.
Looking at the above mongoDB schema what I want is:
Find an expense with the ID match with the _id and need to update the fields with new ones from the req.body.
Just need to update the: expensesType, description, price and status.

[image: MongoDB Schema]

The following code is what I tried to do.
First I need to match the right expense and it works fine but when I try to house.save() show me a message 'house.save is not a function'. So I think maybe I need to use a mongoDB function to get the result.

```
router.put("/editExpense/:id", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  House.find(
    { "expensesHouse._id": id },
    {
      members: 1,
      name: 1,
      description: 1,
      address: 1,
      type: 1,
      user: 1,
      userID: 1,
      userType: 1,
      expensesHouse: { $elemMatch: { _id: id } },
      date: 1
    }
  ).then(house => {
    console.log(house);
    expenseType = req.body.expenseType;
    description = req.body.description;
    price = req.body.price;
    status = req.body.status;

    house.save().then(() => {
      req.flash("success_msg", "Expenses Updated");
      res.redirect("/houses/dashboard");
    });
  });
});
```

****** UPDATED ******

After a search I found this updateOne and after adjusts, this is my final result but this way I delete every record..

```
router.put("/editExpense/:id", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
  House.updateOne(
    { "expensesHouse._id": id },
    {
      members: 1,
      name: 1,
      description: 1,
      address: 1,
      type: 1,
      user: 1,
      userID: 1,
      userType: 1,
      expensesHouse: { $elemMatch: { _id: id } },
      date: 1
    },
    { $set: { "expensesHouse.expenseType": req.body.expenseType } }
  ).then(house => {
    req.flash("success_msg", "Expenses Updated");
    res.redirect("/houses/dashboard");
  });
});
```

*********** RESOLUTION ***********
I just fixed the problem the way I show below.

```
 House.updateOne(
{ "expensesHouse._id": id },
{
  $set: {
    expensesHouse: {
      expenseType: req.body.expenseType,
      description: req.body.description,
      price: req.body.price,
      status: req.body.status
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close to the answer the problem right now that you are having is syntax difference between `find` and `UpdateOne`

This is what `Find` expects, Check [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

`db.collection.find(query, projection)`

This is what `updateOne` expects, Check [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/)

```
 db.collection.updateOne(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ],
     hint:  <document|string>        // Available starting in MongoDB 4.2.1
   }
)
```

See the Difference? Second parameter should be `update` not `projection` because Update one 
returns

- **matchedCount** containing the number of matched documents
- **modifiedCount** containing the number of modified documents
- **upsertedId** containing the _id for the **upserted** document.
- A boolean acknowledged as true if the operation ran with write concern or false if write concern was disabled.

So Your code should be

```
House.updateOne(
    { "expensesHouse._id": id },
    { $set: { "expensesHouse.expenseType": req.body.expenseType } }
  ).then(house => {
    req.flash("success_msg", "Expenses Updated");
    res.redirect("/houses/dashboard");
  });
});
```

Comment: Returns me an error:

MongoError: Cannot create field 'description' in element 

I think it tries to create a new field inside the array I have.

Comment: Should I change the Router.PUT for anything else? It can't works..

Answer (score 0):

```
House.findOneAndUpdate({userId : req.params.userId}, 
    { $set: { "expensesHouse.$[element].status": req.body.status } },
    { multi:true, arrayFilters: [{ "element.userID" : req.params.subUserId }], new:true })
```

Your Api reuquest consist of both the IDs (outer as well as inner) like `/api/update/:userId/:subUserId`